# CSS Grid странное поведение на небольших экранах

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Есть следующий фрагмент разметки:

```
   <div class="card-square">
    <a name="guide_{{ guide.pk }}" href="#guide_{{ guide.pk }}"></a>
    <a href="{% url 'guides:guide' guide.pk %}">
        <div class="card-preview">
            <img src="{{ guide.preview }}">
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
            <h5>{{ guide.guide_name }}</h5>
            <p>{{ guide.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Смысл в том, что картинка и описание обернуты в тег "a", что бы сделать их кликабельными. Контейнер в котором лежат эти карточки является grid-ом. Все ок на большем разрешении, но если уменьшить окно браузера, то ссылка перестает работать, не реагирует на наведение курсора и нажатие.
CSS карточек:

```
.card-square {
    width: 320px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
                0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.card-square a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #616161;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card-preview {
    height: 170px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.card-preview img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}
```

CSS для небольших экранов:

```
@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 1000px) {

    main.mdl-layout__content {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-columns: 50px auto;
        grid-template-areas:
            "menu main"
            "menu pagination";
    }

    main .mdl-layout__container {
        width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

То же без @media выглядит так:

```
main.mdl-layout__content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 220px auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        "menu main"
        "menu pagination";
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

main .mdl-layout__container {
    grid-area: menu;
}
```

CSS контейнера для карточек:

```
.main-sector-1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(340px, 1fr));
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-right: 0px;
    font-family: Roboto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился добавлением z-index, при чем не важно, что 1, что 99, судя по всему, все перекрывало меню, даже будучи закрытым. Веселый js.